# How to call Cplex.AddMIPStart method

Tags: cplex, c#, warm-start

Could you please tell where I can find a method `Cplex.AddMIPStart`? By that I mean in which library and how to link this library to my C# project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside

https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/warm-start-optimization-ac73eef189e9

In the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=am-addmipstart-method-inumvar-double-int32-int32-cplexmipstarteffort-string):

```
Adds a MIP start, defined by a range of numeric variables and corresponding values, with its name and an effort level.

Namespace: ILOG.CPLEX
Assembly: ILOG.CPLEX (in ILOG.CPLEX.dll) Version: 20.1.0.0
```